# How to close the virtual keyboard after reading a number?

Tags: java, android

I'm very newbie in java android. 
i read number by using an EditText which inputType is set to "number".
When i clicked it a virtual keyboard is shown. 
How to close the keyboard after i pressed the key V(The validate key)
Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you want? Is very unclear at least for me, you trying to put a number in an EditText and then hide the keyboard?

Comment: you want to close the keyboard just after clicking V ? please explain more.

Comment: When i clicked my EditText , java android displays a virtual  keyboard containing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way,you should make a helper method and then call it by passing the applicable context.

Call this method after your desired event occurs.

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new View(activity);
    }
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: thanks i added these lines  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0); in the public void onClick(View v)   and it's work

Comment: If it worked,please accept the answer .This will help all the people who will check this thread in future.  #HappyCoding